# Outputting array duplicates

Tags: arrays, duplicates

I'm really stuck to get my array to output duplicate of numbers like this:
2 numbers of length 1,
4 numbers of length 2,
1 numbers of length 3
and so on
any idea how I could achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: What does duplicate means? Two numbers with equal number of digits are duplicate?

Comment: If the array contains 2 1's, 4 2's, 1 3 and then output them as I put above. Sorry I wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the maximum value of given numbers is limited then create a `count` array. For any number `i`, increase its counter `count[i]++`. Finally iterate over count array and find all the counts.

But for unrestricted range of numbers, sort the array in some order and count consecutive occurrences of a number.

Comment: How would I count consecutive occurrences of a number in a sorted array? Sorry I'm new to programming.